# How can I set the SIM900a to Europe?

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

I got a chinese SIM900a module but it can't connect to the network (I live in Europe). Is there a way to get it work on Europe mobile networks?

Comment: Find a provider that still supports GSM. I know that in the USA they are phasing out GSM. Could you tell us the provider you are currently trying to connect to, and in which country?

Comment: I am in Croatia...

Comment: The SIM900A seems to be carrier locked, and will only work in Asia. It appears you can update the firmware to make it work, as described here https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/how-to-flash-the-sim900a-module/

Comment: Thanks. Will check it out? Add reputation?

Comment: Here is a manual in Dutch with all the necessary tools. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1glNtS7zUH_dMQdc8O_W3YZX4h6nKtPWF?usp=sharing